# Convert ASP.NET Core ActionResult<T> object to another type in a filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, action-filter

I have a generic `Result<T>` type that I'm using from my business-level services to return results. This type includes a property with the actual value (`public T Value {get;}`) as well as a status property that indicates Success, NotFound, ValidationError, or other options.

In an API controller, I can evaluate the result of a service call and return an appropriate ActionResult like `NotFound` or `Ok` or `BadRequest`.

I can manually do what I want in the method

```
public ActionResult<Result<Customer>> GetCustomer(int id)
{
    Result<Customer> result = _someService.GetGetCustomer(id);
    if (result.Status == ResultStatus.NotFound) return NotFound();
    if (result.Status == ResultStatus.Invalid)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.ValidationErrors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(error.Key, error.Value);
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    return Ok(result.Value);
}
```

[Example based on source here](https://github.com/ardalis/Result/blob/master/sample/Ardalis.Result.SampleWeb/WeatherForecastFeature/WeatherForecastController.cs#L29-L36)

but I'd like to be able to do this from within an ActionFilter instead.

The problem is I'm not having much success figuring out how to cast the value since I want the filter to work for any kind of `T`. Some pseudo code may help:

```
[TranslateResultToHttp]
public ActionResult<Result<Customer>> GetCustomer(int id)
{
  Result<Customer> result = _someService.GetCustomer(int id);

  return Ok(result);
}
```

In my `TranslateResultToHttpAttribute` I'd need to take the resulting result, look at its value, and if it really was Ok I would replace `Result<Customer>` with just the `Customer`. But if it were a NotFound I would return NotFound, etc.

The problem is the filter has no idea what T the `Result<T>` might be, so I'm having a hard time unpacking the result to get its value, etc.

Comment: Hmm, did you consider a custom action result type instead of a filter?

Comment: No, would that help? I'd still need to somehow convert from that action result type to another type (NotFoundResult, OkResults, etc.).

Comment: Right, if you wanted to use those types, then it might not help. Though the custom one could potentially use the services those results use to write the result as needed.. Just thinking out loud here, not sure if that'd actually work :\

Comment: Or an extension method that converts Result<T> to IActionResult? :)

Comment: You could make your Result type an `IActionResult` and use that directly. Or you return an `ObjectResult<Result<T>>` and then you can update the result in a result filter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Result<T>` type has a non-generic base interface that contains the pure status, you could just return the result directly, getting an implicit object result. And then you can implement a result filter to update the status code:

```
public interface IResult
{
    int Result { get; set; } // could of course be something else
}

public class UpdateResultFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    { }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult && objectResult.Value is IResult result)
        {
            // update status on object result
            objectResult.StatusCode = result.Status;
        }
    }
}
```

In the end, this is the same as returning specific results like `NotFoundResult` or `BadRequestResult` because these are just [`StatusCodeResult`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.statuscoderesult?view=aspnetcore-3.1) with a predefinied status code.